# How to create true spherical spring?

Tags: modeling

I want to create object like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is an addon for that: "add curve: extra objects". Once activated, Shift A/Curve/Add curve spirals, then choose spheric and tune the parameters in the operator panel

Comment: @lemon Should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @RayMairlot, should be a duplicate, finally!! So... I'll just add another way to do it, without the addon (even if I don't know if it is mathematically correct)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way, just to add to the catalogue found by Prashant in another question:

- Add a plane and keep only one segment
- Make an inclination at 45° in front view
- Subdivide a lot (around 100 times)

[image]

- In front view, select one extremity
- Set the proportional editing to enabled and to linear
- Make a "blank" rotation (0°) to adjust the falloff
- Then in top view
- <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate
- Rotate at the maximum possible value
- Rotate again <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the last operation

[image]

Finally, add a cast modifier and let it to sphere with a factor of 1:

[image]

Edit: FYI, that can be done with a single subdivided segment kept horizontal. Rotate with linear falloff and grab Z with spherical falloff.

Comment: Hmm, interesting one, +1.   :)